# vite + jest - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, vite

I migrated the project from create react app to vite and then the tests stop working. I solved already many problems, but right now I stopped and this error and can't move on:

```
  ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { jsx as _jsx, jsxs as _jsxs, Fragment as _Fragment } from "react/jsx-runtime";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

It comes from the my internal UI library inside the project when components are trying to import some of the library component.

index.js <- one file inside UI Library to export all components

```js
module.exports = {
  Button: require('./components/button/Button').default,
}
```

.babelrc

```rc
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env"
  ]
}
```

jest.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
export default {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/jest-config/mocks/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': '<rootDir>/jest-config/mocks/styleMock.js',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!d3|d3-array|internmap|delaunator|robust-predicates)',
  ],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: false,
      useESM: true,
      babelConfig: true,
      plugins: ['babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env'],
      diagnostics: false,
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Renaming the .babelrc file to babel.config.json should fix this.

Comment: @Suniltc it didn't help

Comment: transformIgnorePatterns will only work with babel.config.json. If you are using esm modules in your app, you can add it in transformIgnorePatterns.
Ex: transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!d3|d3-array|internmap|delaunator|robust-predicates|react)',
  ], 
You can also try this to ignore node_modules,
transformIgnorePatterns: [
"/node_modules/"
]